# Grab third element in html table row VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a personal project where I am getting some information from a website. 
The website has a table. I know how to loop through each row and For each row I want to compare information with the contents of the first and fourth columns and, where both are matches to information from my table, copy the content of the fifth column in that row into my table but do not how to go about doing this. 
This is what each row in the table html looks like.

```
<tr class="player_tr_1" data-url="/18/player/1/Pelé">
    <td class="table-row-text" style="text-align: left;">
      <img style="padding: 0;" class="player_img player_right_curve 
        form rating icon gold rare" src="./FIFA 18 Players _ 
        FUTBIN_files/237067.png">                                    
 //Check info here 
       <a href="https://www.futbin.com/18/player/1/Edson%20Arantes" 
         class="player_name_players_table"> CHECK THIS TEXT </a>
     </td> <td><span class="form rating icon gold rare">98</span> </td>
     <td class="">CAM</td>
  //Check info here
     <td class="">CHECK THIS INFO</td>
  //Grab info here
     <td><span class="ps4_color"> GRAB THIS INFO </span></td>
     <td><span class="xb1_color">0</span></td>
     <td><span class="pc_color">0</span></td>
     <td><span class="yellow_players_stat">76</span></td>
     <td>173cm | 5'8"</td>
     <td>77</td>
     <td>516</td>
     <td>2513</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code I have so far:
It iterates through each row in the table and in that loop I need to grab info from that row. I commented in the loop for what I need to do specifically

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        SearchBot
End Sub

'start a new subroutine called SearchBot '
Sub SearchBot()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim X As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim version As String 'string variable that will hold our version '
Dim NumRows As Integer


'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True



' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1
' Select cell a1.
Range("A2").Select
' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.

' screen is updated every time a new price is inserted '
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For X = 2 To NumRows
    ' go to player page with correct name '
    objIE.navigate "https://www.futbin.com/18/players?page=1&search=" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & X).Value


    ' wait '
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    ' loop through each row '
    For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        ' check player name, if correct loop through table to grab price if it is also the right version maybe or'
        ' or grab first elements text content, check if correct name, check 4th element for correct version, grab 5th element, and insert in table '

        'if 1st element = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & X).Value & "" '
        ' And 4th element = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & X).Value Then '
        'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & X).Value = 5th element '
    Next
Next
' click the correct version of the player '


'close the browser
objIE.Quit
MsgBox ("Done")

'exit our SearchBot subroutine '
End Sub
```

EDIT: As you can see in the html, the elements I'm trying to grab do not have class names.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's your *I know how to loop through each row*? Why did you set tags `vb.net`, `vba` and `excel`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried and please also clarify what technology are you using. VBA and VB.NET are not the same, and .NET is only related to VB.NET and Excel (possibly) to VBA.

Comment: hi @JohnyL i set the tags as such because I am using vba and excel. and .net because when I look up visual basic on stack overflow .net questions come up. I'll add in my code shortly in an edit. Forgot to include it at the end.

Comment: What do your code give you so far?  Is there specific command that's giving you an issue?  I'd suggest you start with that many examples of others scraping web pages with VBA; for example, have you searched this site (or Googler)  for "VBA Web Scraping"?

Comment: @ashleedawg Ashlee, so far it goes to the website and goes through each row of the table. I need to grab specifically the 5th element from a row if it has the correct information 1st and 4th column. I have looked at many different questions regarding web scraping but so far I have not found one that I can deploy. I could use a crude and inefficient method of looping through each column and having a counter so I could check just those.

Comment: @pnuts Oh wow, I meant grab from the 5th. No idea how I missed that, thank you pnuts

Comment: @pnuts What is confusing you? I'll try to explain more here. The website has a table in it. The table holds information on players. My excel sheet hold 2 pieces of information that I use to find the correct player. The name, and the version. I iterate through each row in the table to find the correct player based on those pieces of information. So I need to check the textContent of the element in the 1st column, and the element in the 4th column, and if they match my information then I need to grab the textContent from the element of the 5th column and insert that into my sheet.

Comment: @pnuts okay, I've edited the post. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be only one element without any ID/class that you can use to identify it, so that you'll have to get by index while you get the rest by class name.

```
Dim FirstColumn As String
Set FirstColumn = aEle.getElementsByClassName("player_name_players_table")(1).innerText

Dim FourthColumn As String
Set FourthColumn = aEle.getElementsByTagName("td")(4).innerText

Dim FifthColumn As String
Set FifthColumn = aEle.getElementsByClassName("ps4_color")(1).innerText
```

Note that I'm not very used to VBA (I'm a VB.NET guy) so I'm not sure whether all the syntax is correct, nor if the returned arrays are starts at zero or one. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161946/discussion-on-answer-by-visual-vincent-grab-third-element-in-html-table-row-vba).